# can not setMetaTitle for product Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

i am trying to allow customer to add new product from front-end (Market Place).

it works correctly and add product and save it correctly, but the problem is that he can`t save any of (Meta title, Meta Description, Meta Keywords created at and customer id). but it saves other attributes correctly

Here is a sample for my code

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

        $product->setSku($sku);
        $product->setName($name);
        $product->setDescription($description);
        $product->setShortDescription($short_description);
        $product->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2');
        $product->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2');
        $product->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2');
        $product->setUrlKey($url_key);
        $product->setPrice($price);
        $product->setTypeId('simple');
        $product->setAttributeSetId(4); 
        $product->setCategoryIds($categories); 
        $product->setWeight($weight);
        $product->setTaxClassId($tax_class); 
        $product->setVisibility($visibility); 
        $product->setStatus($status);
        $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'));
        $product->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2016') ;
        $product->setNewsToDate('06/30/2016') ;
        $product->setCustomerId(414);
        $gallery[]=$image;
        $product->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array()));
        foreach ($gallery as $image){
            $imagePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/catalog/product/images/' . $image;
            $imageResized = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/catalog/product/compress/' . $image;

            if (!file_exists($imageResized) && file_exists($imagePath)) {
                $imageObj = new Varien_Image($imagePath);
                $imageObj->constrainOnly(TRUE);
                $imageObj->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);
                $imageObj->keepFrame(FALSE);
                $imageObj->resize(600);
                $imageObj->save($imageResized);
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imageResized, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
            }
        }

        $product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));
        $product->save();
        $stockData = $product->getStockData();
        $stockData['qty'] = $qty;
        $stockData['is_in_stock'] = $is_in_stock;
        $stockData['manage_stock'] = $manage_stock;
        $stockData['use_config_manage_stock'] = 0;
        $product->setStockData($stockData);
```

Answer (score 0):

for adding product from frontend you can simple create form like in backend

```
<input name='product[meta_title]' .. />
<input name='product[meta_description]' .. />
<input name='product[meta_keyword]' .. />
<!-- etc... -->
```

and just get post `product` and add to product

```
try {
   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
   $product->addData(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost()['product']);
   $product->save();
} catch(Exception $error) {
   Mage::logException($error);
}
```

for you answer:

> 1. you need catch error by `try catch` instruction...
> 2. try `setData('meta_title','Testing')` maybe you can get error in name method `setMetaTitle()` or this method exist in any rewrite product models
> 3. and try reindex catalog after product save, and clear cache(or disable for develop).

Comment: i already use try and catch but the main problem is that it save all data like description , name ,price , images but not save meta title , meta description and website_id

Comment: @MahmoudAbdElSamad you call method `$product->save()` if you edit product you need set id `setId($id)` or load product `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)` and after save try output id product `var_dump($product->getId())` for look this product in adminhtml interface.

Comment: this is code in creation of product not in edit case , i create module that allow customer to add product (Marketplace)
this code in creation case not in update case to load product data

Comment: @MahmoudAbdElSamad you try call `setData('meta_title','testing');`? and try `setStore(0)` this default store

Comment: meta title saved correctly but website_ids not save correctly

[ $product->setData('website_ids',(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()))); ]

Comment: @MahmoudAbdElSamad what return `Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()`? I think correct `Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId(); `

Comment: it`s return 1 , 
when using `Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();` it is also not working